# How Equivalent $T_1$ Separation Axiom Statements Relate

Tags: general-topology, axioms

The textbook I am following for topology makes the following claim: "The condition that finite point sets be closed has been given a name of its own: it is called the $T_1$ axiom."

However, most explanations of the $T_1$ axiom I find online describe it as "For any two points $x,y \in X$, there exist open sets $U$ and $V$ such that $x \in U$, $x \notin V$, $y \in V$, $y \notin U$.

I don't understand how these two statements are equivalent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call $U_x$ the open set containing $x$ but not $y$. Take the union of the $U_x$'s to get that the complement of each point $\{y\}$ is open.  Thus the point is closed.

The converse follows because when the point is closed, its complement is open.

Comment: Are you saying to take $\cup_{x\neq y} U_x$ to get the union of open sets containing every point except $y$, using the fact the union of open sets is open, then taking the complement of that to say that $y$ is closed? And does the converse follow because when you assume finite point sets are closed, the complement is open, and the complement of a singleton can be expressed as a union of open sets containing all other points? Sorry I'm new to this and trivial steps go over my head.

Comment: Wait no, the complement of the closed set $\{y\}$ is open, and contains $x$ when $x \neq y$, so there exists an open set that contains $x$ but not $y$, got it.

Comment: Right.  That's it.